# C# DataGridView bound to member of List<DataTable> inside object

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

I have the following business object:

```
public class MyObject
{
  // Some public properties that are bound to text boxes, etc on the form
  public string Customer { get; set; }
  public int JobNumber { get; set; }

  // Each DataTable in this list consists of a single column of doubles
  // representing the error in a series of measurements (ex. -.0002, -.0003, .0002, etc)
  public List<DataTable> MeasurementErrors {get; set; }

  public MyObject
  {
    // Code in here creates the first DataTable with the first measurement (always zero)
    // and adds it to the MeasurementErrors list
    errors = new DataTable();
    errors.TableName = "MeasurementErrors";
    errors.Columns.Add("Error", typeof(double));
    errors.Rows.Add(0.0);
    MeasurementErrors.Add(errors); // initial table added to the list
  }
}
```

I've had no problems binding Customer and JobNumber and all the other basic properties to text boxes on the entry form (VS generated a BindingSource and set up all those controls for me).

What I'm having trouble with is binding one of the DataTables in MeasurementErrors to a DataGridView control. The table to bind should be chosen by a NumericUpDown control and then there will be a simple "Add" button to generate a new table and add it to MeasurementErrors (and a delete button if necessary). How do I set up the DataSource and DataMember properties of the DataGridView to bind to MeasurementErrors[value of UpDownControl]?

I'm not fixed on using DataTables but from what I've read that is the preferred way of binding to a DataGridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `List<T>` is not bindable. Use an `IList<T>` instead as the property return type.

```
public IList<DataTable> MeasurementErrors { get; set; }
```

Plus, it is better recommended to use a internal list for list members and make it a read-only property, depending on your needs, always.

```
public class MyObject {
    private IList<DataTable> _measurementErrors;

    public MyObject() {
        _measurementErrors = new List<DataTable>();
    }

    // This way you make sure to never have a null reference, and don't give 
    // out the control over your list to the user.
    public IList<DataTable> MeasurementErrors {
        get {
            return _measurementErrors;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT #1**

> IList doesn't seem to be serializable so it is simply left out of the resulting xml file. Is there a simple way to make this IList serializable?

If your instance of `IList<T>` is a `List<T>` under the hood, then I suggest you to type-cast your `IList<T>` to a `List<T>` for the sake of serialization. And if that fails, then create a new list from its content.

```
var list = myObject1.MeasurementErrors as List<DataTable> ?? new List<DataTable>(myObject1.MeasurementErrors);
```

For more details about `?? Operator`, please refer to MSDN: [`?? Operator (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

In short, it is the equivalence of writing:

```
var list = (myObject1.MeasurementErrors as List<DataTable>) == null ? 
            new List<DataTable>(myObject1.MeasurementErrors) : 
            myObject1.MeasurementErrors as List<DataTable>;
```

Or if you prefer:

```
var list = myObject1.MeasurementErrors as List<DataTable>;

if (list == null)
    list = new List<DataTable>(myObject1.MeasurementErrors);
```

I hope this information is not more confusing than helping.

Comment: I've implemented my list of DataTables using IList and it seems to work, but this has added another wrinkle to the project. Prior to this where I only had a single DataTable, I was using an XmlSerializer to save MyObject to a file. IList doesn't seem to be serializable so it is simply left out of the resulting xml file. Is there a simple way to make this IList serializable?

Comment: Re: EDIT #1 - Thanks, creating a separate public property that I have no intention of actually using with _measurementErrors typecasted to a List worked to serialize MyObject with all the data. Now I just need to work out how to bind the IList property to the DataGridView while specifying the index.

Comment: You don't actually need to create another property, but just typecast your `MeasurementErrors` when serializing it. I have not worked much with `Serialization`, so perhaps I'm missing something here. Yet, I don't get your point of binding the `IList` to the `DataGridView` while specifying an index. Can't you just do `DataGridView.DataSource = IList<DataTable>`?

Comment: I'm running the XmlSerialize on an instance of MyObject so I don't really have the opportunity to typecast the IList property at that time. Regarding the DataSource = IList, I want to display/edit the contents of only a single DataTable within that IList so I need to choose which one of those DataTables is active in the DataGridView.

Comment: I apparently didn't think this through enough before I raced off to implement it. Why don't I just add another column to a single DataTable with my index rather than create an array of DataTables? Using an IList will definitely come in handy with future data binding situations so I greatly appreciate your help.